# Flutter: Access Stored Sharedpreference value from Other Pages

Tags: sharedpreferences, flutter

I'm storing a value in a page called `page1.dart`. I want to access the stored value from `page2.dart` or `page3.dart`. How can I achieve this?

Comment: what are using to swipe the screens

Comment: @RaoufRahiche using tabview

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I have stored a string in 1st screen,then retrieved the stored value from the second screen by the following code

PAGE 1:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:trial/class2.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  String _email = '';

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _loadCounter();
  }

  _loadCounter() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      _email = (prefs.getString('email') ?? '');
    });
  }

  _incrementCounter() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      _email = "a@gmail.com";
    });
    prefs.setString('email', _email);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("title"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              '$_email',
            ),
            new RaisedButton(
              child: new Text("next2"),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.push(context,
                    new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => new Next()));
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

PAGE 2:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
String _email='';
class Next extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _NextState createState() => _NextState();
}

class _NextState extends State<Next> {
    @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _loadCounter();
  }

  _loadCounter() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      _email = (prefs.getString('email')??'');
    });
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Container(
      child: new Text("read value from sharepreference is:"+_email),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 43):

Flutter shared preferences is actually implemented as an in-memory cache. The first time that you call `SharedPreferences.getInstance()` all the current values are read from NSUserDefaults (on iOS) and SharedPreferences (on Android) and cached in memory. This involves channels, so is async. The Future returns a singleton class that wraps this cache. Any subsequent calls to getInstance return this singleton class.

When you get a value from shared preferences the value is simply fetched from the in-memory cache. When you set a value the cache is immediately updated and an async method started to write it back to the operating system. (You can wait for confirmation of completion of that, but you don't have to.) Note that the reads and writes from and to the cache are synchronous, so you have immediate access to that cache of settings. (It may take a moment to reach the operating system so the in-memory cache isn't guaranteed to match the device preferences, but this should only happen under error conditions.)

The reason why this is interesting is that once you get the result of `SharedPreferences.getInstance()` you can read and write values synchronously. Since the instance is singleton it seems reasonable to keep a copy of it. In particular, you can make your main async and fetch it there.

```
SharedPreferences sp;

void main() async {
  sp = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  runApp(new MyApp());
}
```

This allows you to refer to `sp` throughout your code:

```
  onPressed: () {
    sp.setString('abc', 'def');
  },
```

knowing that the in-memory cache is consistent. In particular, any values set in one page can be got in another page following navigation.

Having said all that, you should probably think of your stored preferences as just one part of your state, which just happens to get initialized at startup and on setting it fires off a background task to persist it automatically. You could then deal with the preferences in the same way as the rest of your state however you are doing that (InheritedWidget + controller, Redux, Streams, etc.).

Comment: thnx a lot but happily i'm not going to touch the sharedpreference values anymore,i just want to store the user name untill the app is uninstalled,i won't allow him to change the values in another pages,once i achieved the result,ill update with a Answer solved Tick mark,Thanks

Comment: This trick helped me.  Setting a pref in page 1 and going to page 2 is just masking the issue.  I wanted to set something in 1 and see it in 1 and this change allowed my shared prefs to be ready to go at the app level rather than relying on the answer below.

Comment: It's a good approach by the way. It enables you not to add `async` keyword to every method where you need to get the value from sharedPrefs. Just instantiate it once, make it `static` and then call it from everywhere in the code without waiting.

Comment: October 2020, This is still the best answer for a singleton and accessing on different part of the app

Comment: Doesn't this create a cyclic dependency?

Comment: @NamithaReval Do you mean that `page1.dart` needs to import `page2.dart` (in this simple example) and vice-versa? Yes, but that's not a problem.

Comment: Hi @RichardHeap, yes, that's what I meant. Usually, cyclic dependencies aren't a good idea in the long run.

Comment: @NamithaReval they are perfectly normal in Dart, but it you want to remove it, move the line `SharedPreferences sp;` to a 3rd source file, and have the first 2 import that.

Comment: Why not pass the values instead? That can bypass a global variable as well. Let me write an answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you have to need to get values of `SharePreferences` in multiple class then you can put the common get and set methods of **SharedPreference** in static methods in a class.

```
 import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
 class SharedPrefUtils {

    static saveStr(String key, String message) async {
       final SharedPreferences pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
       pref.setString(key, message);
    }

    static readPrefStr(String key) async {
        final SharedPreferences pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
        return pref.getString(key);
    }

 }
```

Then, in any other class, use `SharedPrefUtils.readPrefStr(String key);`.

Answer (score 2):

Pass the shared preferences from main to all the pages where you want it. I've Page1.dart as an example below. The same method can be used to pass the parameter on to any other class in any other file.

Page1.dart

```
void main() async {

  // Note that this line is required, otherwise flutter throws an error 
  // about using binary messenger before runApp()
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  SharedPreferences sharedPref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  runApp(new MyApp(sharedPref));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final SharedPreferences sharedPref;

  MyApp(this.sharedPref);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(sharedPref),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final SharedPreferences sharedPref;

  MyHomePage(this.sharedPref);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  String _email = '';

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    widget.sharedPref.setString('email', _email);
  }

  // ... rest of your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to use SharedPreferences in flutter is to assign the instance to a global variable, initialised in your `main` function, making the function `async`.

Generally, in flutter, the `main` function is only used to set up the routes to other screens and run the app, so if your starting route is any other screen, then by the time you reach that screen and require the use of the SharedPreferences instance, it's available.

No need for initialisation functions, really.