# Flutter: Futures and shared preferences

Tags: asynchronous, dart, flutter, future

I have a function called 'retrieveDB' that uses shared_preferences.dart plugin to retrieve data that I will use for deciding whether what collection/document name will I retrieve from Firestore. I've initialized usersDB and notifDoc = "" at the top of the class.

```
    Future retrieveDB() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    String db = prefs.getString('db');

    if (db == "MISS") {
      usersDB = "users_miss";
      notifDoc = "notifTokenMISS";
    } else if (db == "SDD") {
      usersDB = "users";
      notifDoc = "notifToken";
    }
    }
```

I placed 'retrieveDB' first thing in initState() (after super.initState()).

My problem(I think) is that shared_preferences uses Future and it pauses its execution and proceeds with other functions that retrieves data from Firestore leaving the document names (usersDB and notifDoc = "") empty thus producing errors. Is there a way to wait for 'retrieveDB' first before proceeding with other functions or is there any place that I can put 'retrieveDB' that it will be executed/finished first? Or is there any better logic in implementing what I want?

Comment: See [also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51215064/flutter-access-stored-sharedpreference-value-from-other-pages/51228189#51228189)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Async is contagious. You can't go back from async to sync.
If a function uses `async` you need to use `await` when you call it to ensure following code executes only after the async function completed:

```
Future foo() async {
  await retrieveDB();
  // other code that depends on the result or side effects of retrieveDB()
}
```

Comment: Hi Gunter. What if the other code that depends on the result of retrieveDB() is on other functions? In my case, retrieveeDB() is in initState and other function that needs its output is in my build. Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: Use a FutureBuilder in `build` and call ’retrieveDB from there

Answer (score 0):

Use anonymous functions instead

```
@override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
    () async {
    await retrieveDB();
    }
    }
```