# Saving and loading, shared preferences

Tags: dart, flutter

```
List<double> timersValuesList = [30.0, 60.0, 90.0, 120.0, 150.0, 180.0];

void saveSharedPreferences() async {
  // from List of double to a List of String
  List<String> convertedTimerValues = timersValuesList.map((i) => i.toString()).toList();
  // getting the instance of sharedPreferences as Object prefs
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  // taking my List as key of "mylist", if it doesn't exist create empty List, this is List of String
  List<String> myList = (prefs.getStringList('mylist') ?? List<String>());
  //saving the List of String as key"mylist"
  await prefs.setStringList('mylist', convertedTimerValues);
}

void loadSharedPreferences() async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  List<String> myList = (prefs.getStringList('mylist') ?? List<String>());
  List<double> myOriginalList = myList.map((i)=> double.parse(i)).toList();
  timersValuesList = myOriginalList;
//    print('Your list  $myOriginalList');
}
```

I tried to use SharedPreferences in this file for saving and loading a List of 6 double values, which are used in other widget and could be modified. Now the problem is that everytime I open my app it doesn't make me see updated and modified values, but always the first one I declared for default. For example. I edit my first value and it becomes like this.

```
timersValuesList[0] = 35
```

then I save it and exit the app. When I relaunch the app it shows me values of 30 not 35 like it should be. But if I edit for example with a +1, it jumps directly to 36 so it makes me thing that value was saved but was not visualized correctly at first launch. After that adding values work correctly. Can someone help me? I cannot find a way to do this. Maybe I should put in the saving function the default values in case doesn't exist any file saved already? thanks help with code of saving and loading a list of double too, because I don't think I'm doing it well. Thanks again.

I made this. ( I could call in the initState any async function so I called an external one). But i get error: "NoSuchMethodError: The method "[]" was called on null. 
Receiver: null
Tried calling: "

```
class _SettingsPageState extends State<SettingsPage> {
  List<double> timersList;

  @override initState()  {
    super.initState();
    callLoad();
  }
  Future callLoad() async {
    timersList = await loadTimers();
  }

  void saveTimers(List<double> timersList) async {
    List<String> convertedTimerValues = timersList.map((i) => i.toString()).toList();
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    await prefs.setStringList('TimerList', convertedTimerValues);
  }

  Future<List<double>> loadTimers() async {
    List<double> defaultTimersList = [30.0, 60.0, 90.0, 120.0, 150.0, 180.0];
    List<double> savedTimerList;
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    List<String> myList =  prefs.getStringList('TimerList');
    if (myList == null ){
      return defaultTimersList;
    } else{
      savedTimerList = myList.map((i)=> double.parse(i)).toList();
      return savedTimerList;
    }
  }
```

I edit like your code suggest. But I get this error, but the screen been loads with the correct value.

```
I/flutter ( 9290): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter ( 9290): The following RangeError was thrown building SettingsPage(dirty, dependencies: [MediaQuery], state:
I/flutter ( 9290): _SettingsPageState#c0ade):
I/flutter ( 9290): RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0
I/flutter ( 9290): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
I/flutter ( 9290): #0      List.[] (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:145:60)
I/flutter ( 9290): #1      _SettingsPageState.build (package:my_fitness_tools/pages/settings_page.dart:175:45)
I/flutter ( 9290): #2      StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3825:27)
I/flutter ( 9290): #3      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3739:15)
I/flutter ( 9290): #4      Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3565:5)
I/flutter ( 9290): #5      ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3722:5)
I/flutter ( 9290): #6      StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3864:11)
I/flutter ( 9290): #7      ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3717:5)
I/flutter ( 9290): #8      Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2961:14)
I/flutter ( 9290): #9      Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2764:12)
I/flutter ( 9290): #10     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4876:14)
I/flutter ( 9290): #11     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2961:14)
I/flutter ( 9290): #12     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2764:12)
```

This is my Scaffold.

```
Scaffold(
          appBar: new AppBar(
            backgroundColor: Options.selectedTheme.primaryColorDark,
            centerTitle: true,
            title: Text("Settings"),
          ),
          drawer: DrawerApp(),
          body:
          new Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
            new Container(
              decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                  image: new DecorationImage(
                      image: new AssetImage("assets/backgrounds/Sfondo.jpg"),
                      fit: BoxFit.fill)),
            ),
            ListView( // vertical listview
              children: <Widget>[
                //Inizio oggetti in ordine verticale della pagina.
                SizedBox(
                  height: 10.0,
                ),
                titleSettings("Timers"),
                Container(
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                  child: ListView( // horizontal Listview
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      timerColumn(timersList[0], 0), // line 175
                      timerColumn(timersList[1], 1),
                      timerColumn(timersList[2], 2),
                      timerColumn(timersList[3], 3),
                      timerColumn(timersList[4], 4),
                      timerColumn(timersList[5], 5),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            )
```

Editing the List timersList = [0,0,0,0,0,0] fixed that.
But I have a question. If I want to use now those values in another file. I have made the same exact function for loading. But I get this error.
[image]
Same thing on declaring everything and function but why it wants to be static instead the file before didn't?

Answer (score 1):

This is almost certainly to do with the order of execution. You need to look for the answer in the code that you haven't shown.

1. widget state created
2. [30.0, etc assigned to `timersValueList`
3. `initState` called, which presumably calls...
4. `loadSharedPreferences` called, but suspends awaiting `getInstance`, allowing...
5. framework calls `build` - shows current value (30)
6. `getInstance` completes, so `loadSharedPreferences` continues assigning [35.0, etc to `timersValueList`
7. nothing informs the widget that its state has changed until you do an update.

Add a call to `setState` at the end of `loadSharedPreferences` to inform the framework of the change.

```
  void loadSharedPreferences() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    List<String> myList = prefs.getStringList('mylist') ?? ['30', '60', '90'];
    List<double> myOriginalList = myList.map((i) => double.parse(i)).toList();
    setState(() {
      timersValuesList = myOriginalList;
    });
  }
```

**Edit**

I'd change your `State` to this:

```
class _SettingsPageState extends State<SettingsPage> {
  List<double> timersList;

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    loadTimers();
  }

  saveTimers(List<double> timersList) async {
    List<String> convertedTimerValues = timersList.map((i) => '$i').toList();
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.setStringList('TimerList', convertedTimerValues);
  }

  loadTimers() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    List<String> myList = prefs.getStringList('TimerList');
    setState(() {
      timersList = (myList == null)
          ? [30.0, 60.0, 90.0, 120.0, 150.0, 180.0]
          : myList.map((i) => double.parse(i)).toList();
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (timersList == null) return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
    return Whatever(/* Fill me in with the normal page*/);
  }
}
```

You need to assign to `timersList` inside a `setState` so that the framework knows that you've changed the state! This will cause it to rebuild the widget. Note, that in the `build` you have to cope with `timersList` being null. It being null indicates that you are still waiting for stuff to happen, so should render a placeholder.

Comment: I understand what you mean. It really makes sense. However how can I make it to assign at first the value loaded in the sharedPreferences and if doesn't exist a default value? Your help is really appreciated. Thank you

Comment: I tried something. If you could give me some help it would be really appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: At line 175 of that file you are trying to reference the first (zero'th) element of an empty array - probably. Just fix it :-) Standard debugging from this point on. Start adding some print statements.

Comment: I edited the code. Thank you for your help. I need to fix this.

Comment: "Warning: The right-hand side of an initializer does not have access to this." See https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour So, you cannot initialize `rimanenza1` with anything other than a constant or something static. You cannot initialize it with something that itself could not have been initialized.

Comment: Where do you test, before line 175, that `timersList` has been initialized. As in, `if (timersList == null) return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());`, or similar?

Comment: But so how can I initialize those values with the ones in sharedpreferences? I mean "rimanenza1" and others. Because I've tried to put there timerList = [0,0,0,0,0,0] but then it shows me those values in my widgets where I use that array, even if I call the loading of sharedpreferences in the initState() like the other page. how Should I initialize something that depends on the SharedPreferences without having this error? What is the common way to do it? I cannot find. I would like to leave timerList = [] to not have any mock value eventually but only sharedPreferences or default ones.

Comment: Or maybe the best question I have is: How is the right way to accesso sharedPreferences from everywhere so I can access those values since the start loading from the initState before the app draws on screen? Is there something you can show me or link me? Is the best way to make a separate class to load values? Can you show me something. Thank you really much. You are helping a lot

Comment: Please see this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51215064/flutter-access-stored-sharedpreference-value-from-other-pages/51228189#51228189 Use the 'cheat' shown there for now to remove the need to deal with futures.

Comment: thank you for your answer. However I would like to use correctly sharedPreferences but I just can't load variables on startup since SharedPreferences are async it gives me problem. I have no problem using future but I just don't know how to do it. If it doesn't really bother you could show me with my code how to do it? In brief I would like to load those variables in startup using sharedPreferences the correct way.

Comment: That feels like a new question. Why don't you create a new question.

Comment: Looking back up the comments you ask "how can I start loading from init state before the app draws on the screen". That's impossible. While init state runs before build, doing anything async is pretty much guaranteed to finish after the first build of the widget. This is why you need to deal with builds that happen before the future completes and after the future completes. Even with FutureBuilder you have to deal with that. The 'cheat' method solves that for shared preferences.

Comment: For cheat method you mean making the main function async? But the "cheat" is the correct  and official way to load data in the first build too? Could it be so tricky? or it does seems like this to me. Thank you for your help

Comment: It works great. Of course, you don't want to do really long-running things like http during main, but reading shared prefs into memory works fine.