# How does an app remain signedIn with Google after terminating and re-opening it

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences, google-signin

I am using [GoogleSignIn](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/google_sign_in) plugin for Flutter and able to successfully signin in to Google on my simple flutter app.

Once signed in to Google, I need to keep a track of that in the app (and store tokens in a backend service) and not ask user to login again everytime the application is opened (after terminating/closing the app).

I was planning to store the idToken in the sharedPreferences so that on every invocation of the app I could read the token value and determine if the user had already signedIn in the past.

However, I notice that this is how the app is currently working even without me storing the tokens and adding my custom logic (that is, on re-opening the app, it still stays in signedIn state).

My question is, how is it achieving this behavior with out me writing any code to achieve this?

I have tried to look in to the sharedPreferences but I do not see any tokens or identifiers being stored by the Google_sign_in flutter plugin. How is this happening?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flutter: Access Stored Sharedpreference value from Other Pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51215064/flutter-access-stored-sharedpreference-value-from-other-pages)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Android, Flutter's Google Sign-In plugin uses the [GoogleSignIn API for Android](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/GoogleSignIn), which is built into the OS and handles persistence for you.

Comment: thanks, that explains how it was able to identify a user who had previously signedIn.