# How to initialize SharedPreferences using a class constructor?

Tags: flutter, dart

I woudl like to initialize a private SharedPreferences field and seems a good place for it is using a constructor. But as long as `SharedPreferences.getInstance()` returns a Future a compiler can not use await because of `The await expression can only be used in an async function.`. Otherwise it is impossible to make the constructor body as async. So how to make it?

```
GetIt getIt = GetIt.instance;

void setupLocator() {
  getIt.registerSingleton<LocalStorageService>(LocalStorageService());
}

class LocalStorageService {
  SharedPreferences _prefs;
  LocalStorageService() : _prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance(); //error
  ...
}
```

It is possible to make an additional function to call the `setupLocator()` and make it `async` and then use it inside main() method awaiting a result and passing an instance of SharedPreferences into constructor of `LocalStorageService` as an argument, but I would prefer to initialize it inside the `LocalStorageService` class.

Comment: Check this old answer too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51215064/flutter-access-stored-sharedpreference-value-from-other-pages/51228189#51228189 but remember that you'll likely need to add `WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();` in `main` these days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using `GetIt`, I suggest you to use `registerSingletonAsync` method

```dart
  await getIt.registerSingletonAsync<LocalStorageService>(() async {
    final pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return LocalStorageService(pref);
  });
```

I personally don't like creating it in a constructor since maybe another class is dependent on it and it will get a null variable before constructing and it will cause problems.

Consider that you can also register the `SharedPreferences` in memory and create the `LocalStorageService` like this

```dart
  await getIt.registerSingletonAsync<SharedPreferences>(() async {
    return SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  });

  getIt.registerSinglenton<LocalStorageService>(
   () => LocalStorageService(prefs: getIt()),
  );
```

Comment: registerSingletonAsync is perfectly fit although I didn't use it before, and with it there is no need of `WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized()` anymore

Answer (score 0):

You should check this question:
[Calling an async method from component constructor in Dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38933801/calling-an-async-method-from-component-constructor-in-dart)

I think you can do something like this - just keep in mind your _prefs would not be available immediately after the object is created.

```
GetIt getIt = GetIt.instance;

void setupLocator() {
  getIt.registerSingleton<LocalStorageService>(LocalStorageService());
}

class LocalStorageService {
  SharedPreferences _prefs;
  LocalStorageService() : SharedPreferences.getInstance().then((prefs) => _prefs=prefs); 
  ...
}
```