# Flutter: pause code execution to initialize SharedPreferences on startup

Tags: flutter

I read other answers about initializing SharedPreferences in Flutter app (e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49958340/2463035)), but I want to take another route: initialize SharedPreferences object once at the very beginning, and then just pass it around to specific clients as required (a.k.a. dependency injection).

I tried to make my main method async and then use await:

```
void main() async {
  var prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  runApp(MyApp(prefs));
}
```

Intuitively, I expected that the execution will halt until `prefs` is initialized, and then proceeds to `runApp`. Unfortunately, I get a white screen instead of my UI, so I guess I'm missing something here.

I also tried to use `then`:

```
void main() async {
  SharedPreferences.getInstance().then((prefs) => runApp(MyApp(prefs)));
}
```

Same result: white screen.

Is there a way to initialize SharedPreference in this manner in Flutter?

Comment: instead of initializing shared pref in the main method can't you do the same later?

Comment: @OMiShah I want to initialize this object just once, and then pass a reference around. If there is a way to do that in MyApp, then it's also alright. However, I don't want to initialize SharedPreferences in all widgets that will require this feature.

Comment: I had to make an edit to change my vote from negative since I made that by mistake. never mind :P

Answer (score 8, accepted):

add this before you preference instance

```dart
 WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
```

Comment: This works! Thanks. Any side effects of this call that I need to be aware of?

Comment: that just initialize futter context  for methodChannel
becuase preference in flutter use native code
also you can used  in the test if you want to initialize things before runApp or testWidget  you should add that line

Comment: I am having the same issue. Even though I put this line still getting instance issue.